# How to add divs with some classess to another div (inside each other) in html / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to list my products from database by clicking on category in html/view.
Firstly I created it in HTML (static) just to check how this is going to look, and it looks lik this:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top: -15px;">

        <div  class="products row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-holder">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/coke.png">
                    <p class="product-title">
                        Product no1
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-holder">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pepsi.png">
                    <p class="product-title">
                        Product no2
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-holder">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/coffe.png">
                    <p class="product-title">
                        Product no3
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And now I want to create this block dynamically:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="product-holder">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/coffe.png">
           <p class="product-title">
                Product no N
           </p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
<script>
    function onSelectGroup(Id) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "Products/GetProductsByCategoryId",
            data: { categoryId: Id }
        })
.done(function (response) {
    //In response I am getting my products, looping through them to create divs like in code above
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

        //<div class="col-md-3">
        //       <div class="article-holder">
        //           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/picture_not_available_400-300.png">
        //           <p class="product-title">
        //               Product no 1
        //           </p>
        //       </div>
        //   </div>

        //Trying to append it to my .product class because it's parent of this divs above
      $(".products").append('<div class="col-md-3"></div>');
      $(".products).appendChild('<div class="article-holder"></div>');
    }
})};
</script>
```

But this is not working unfortunatelly... I tried few another things, but this appendings are not working as expected :/

Thanks guys for any help
Cheers

Comment: Do you have missing `"`. For example here, (`$(".products).`) ???

Comment: @Shyju Yes because I did not copy it as it is in my visual studio, now I will edit it

Comment: What I understand so far you want to create your product divs dynamically and your main div is products and your product HTML is  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="product-holder">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/coffe.png">
           <p class="product-title">
                Product no N
           </p>
     </div>
 </div> right?

Comment: Instead of manually building the HTML markup in js, you might consider sending a partial view result (instead of JSON array), which IMHO, might be less error prone

Comment: @Shyju could you please post an example of that, I would accept it as answer because it is as you said less error prone and more professional way to solve this?

Comment: I did not say it is the more professional way! It is just my personal choice.

Comment: Is it always 3 items in a row ?

Comment: @Shyju well, because I consider you as a professional, and because it's your personal choise logicly I can conclude, your way is more professional way.

Comment: @Shyju no, there is as many items as there is inside of a product category..

Comment: @billy_56 i posted an answer to get the view result instead of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many answers posted for the question which might solve the issue with the javascript code. **I am posting a different approach as OP specifically requested for it in the comments.**

At times, i do not like to build complex HTML markup in javascript with jQuery ( i afraid i might make typos (missing `"`" or `'` etc..). In that case, i would like to have my action method return a view result (the HTML markup) as the response of my ajax call and i can simply update the DOM with that as needed.

```
public ActionResult GetProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId)
{
    var p = db.Products.Where(a=>a.CategoryId==categoryId).ToList();
    return PartialView("ProductList",p);
}
```

Now i will have a partial view called `ProductList.cshtml`, which is strongly typed to a list of products and i can loop through the items passed to it and render whatever markup i want.

Here is a simple example where i am rendering a div with css class `col-md-3` for each item in the collection passed to it. You can update it to render whatever markup you want to render.

```
@model List<Product>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="product-holder">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="@item.ImageUrl">
            <p class="product-title">
                @item.Name
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now all i have to do is, call this action method, and use the response to update my DOM. Let's give an Id to the container div which we will update

```
<div class="col-md-8" >
    <div id="product-list" class="products row">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the ajax call receives a response from server, update the inner html of the DOM element with Id `product-list`

```
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetProductsByCategoryId","Products")",
        data: { categoryId: 2345 }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        $("#product-list").html(response);
    }).fail(function(a, a, e) {
        alert(e);
    });
```

Keep in mind that, n**ow you are getting a bigger payload** (the resulting HTML) 
 from the server compared to the JSON data. **So use this approach as you feel appropriate to do so**. With this approach, i can use the C# methods in my partial view (For example, to build the path to an image in a location/ use Html helper methods etc)

Answer (score 0):

I you create the dom element like any string, and append it to the container

```js
 function onSelectGroup(Id) {
       
    //In response I am getting my products, looping through them to create divs like in code above
    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {

         let item = `<div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="article-holder">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="images/picture_not_available_400-300.png">
                   <p class="product-title">
                       Product no ${i}
                  </p>
               </div>
           </div>`

        //Trying to append it to my .product class because it's parent of this divs above
      $(".products").append(item);
    }

};
onSelectGroup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top: -15px;">

        <div  class="products row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-holder">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/coke.png">
                    <p class="product-title">
                        Product no1
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-holder">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/pepsi.png">
                    <p class="product-title">
                        Product no2
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-holder">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/coffe.png">
                    <p class="product-title">
                        Product no3
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new element with jquery and fill it properly

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

    //<div class="col-md-3">
    //       <div class="article-holder">
    //           <img class="img-responsive" src="images/picture_not_available_400-300.png">
    //           <p class="product-title">
    //               Product no 1
    //           </p>
    //       </div>
    //   </div>

    //Trying to append it to my .product class because it's parent of this divs above
  var newelem = $('<div class="col-md-3"></div>');
  var artholder = $('<div class="article-holder"></div>');
  newelem.append(artholder);
  artholder.append(<your-image><your article title>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You was close; all you needed to do was create an element for each item in the results object. I've used test data in the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/tw0vrpyy/

```
var response = {
    item1: {
        id: "id1",
        title: "title1",
      img: "img_src1.jpg"
    },
    item2: {
        id: "id2",
        title: "title2",
      img: "img_src2.jpg"
    }
  };

var product = document.getElementsByClassName('response')[0];

Object.keys(response).forEach(function(key) {

    var el = '<div class="col-md-3">' +
                        '<div class="article-holder">' + 
              '<img class="img-responsive" src="'+ response[key].img +'">' + 
              '<p class="product-title">' + 
              response[key].title + 
              '</p>' + 
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';

        product.innerHTML += el;
});
```